How are far from equilibrium systems studied analytically?
I've read about stuff having to do with complex systems where some pretty wacky stuff happens, mostly involving "phase changes", which as I understand don't really have much to do with traditional thermodynamical phase changes and instead use the nomenclature available in dynamical systems theory. I would like answers to both questions if possible:

Are there ways to obtain state equations for far from equilibrium chemical reactions, like the Brusselator? It would be interesting to be able to describe volume and pressure changes associated to their evolution.
What are some good traditional analyses used for far from equilibrium systems, other than linearization of the equations?

I'm working with a reaction-diffusion system but all I've been able to find so far has to do with linearization methods to study the PDE system and maybe get a dispersion relation, however, linearizing my equations makes them really uninteresting for my model. Instead of having to grapple with the second terms of my Taylor expansion to get some useful insights I was hoping for something a bit more down to earth where I can draw meaningful insights about the thermodynamic variables at play.

If the answer you are seeking was known, there would surely be a lot of Nobel Prizes associated with it! But I can make some relatively useful comments.

When you say: "It would be interesting to be able to describe volume and pressure changes"; it is not so trivial. An equation of state does not always exist out of equilibrium. In the particular case I'm linking, they show that the mechanical pressure (momentum exchange on a wall) is not the same as a "thermodynamic one". More precisely, that the pressure depends on the particular interactions with the wall. This already tells you that you lose a lot of the generality of thermodynamics when you go to non-equilibrium.

If an equation of state can be found, you need to start from the microscopic system. Then, coarse-grained it to the mesoscopic or macroscopic scale in order to relate macroscopic parameters and microscopic ones. The Brusselator you give as an example is just a population dynamics. You don't have enough thermodynamic field to do anything. You would need to include at least a temperature field I guess, that could control the rate of the reaction. The pressure could probably be determined through an equation of state that would relate the temperature, concentration of chemical species and the pressure. But this is a very complicated task that would require a microscopic approach where you have some chemical agents that change type, diffuse and exchange momentum (how else could you define the pressure in this context except through the Virial pressure? Perhaps using the work performed on a Wall.). In any case, as the Brusselator stands, it's meaningless to talk about pressure or volume (except the volume that is fixed by your simulation box).

Usually, one linearizes hydrodynamic-like equations because it reveals a lot of information about the stability of the system. For example, the homogeneous state of the Brusselator is unstable. This is easily seen by looking at small perturbations around the homogeneous state. They can prove to be either completely unstable or stable but oscillatory or both... Then, if you wish to see what kind of pattern will form (waves, bands, bubbles, ...), you have to work a little harder, and this becomes the realm of non-linearity and of pattern-selection which was a hot topic in the 80-90's. You can learn more about that in the book: 
Pattern Formation and Dynamics in Nonequilibrium Systems or on the well-known review by Hohenberg and Cross. But as far as I know, if there is something interesting in your system (such as instability), you will know it from the linearization. Going beyond the linear order just allows you to see what kind of pattern will be selected.

About the methods one can use out of equilibrium... Well, it depends on the system :). Some (classical, not quantum) examples include: the Langevin equation, stochastic Thermodynamics, Fokker-Planck equation, Linear response theory, Boltzmann equation, Master equation, Van Kampen's expansion, Onsager-Machlup/Martin-Siggia-Rose-Janssen-De-Dominicis formalisms, Hydrodynamic equation, extended irreversible thermodynamics, GENERIC, dissipative/Poisson bracket formalism, dynamical functional theory, phase field modelling, trajectory ensemble, large deviation theory (which is very general), Markov chains. And the list continues. It's not even because we don't have a general theory of non-equilibrium statistical mechanics because if I wanted to give you a list of methods for equilibrium statistical physics, the list would be just as long. Without knowing much more about your system, it's complicated to say much less!


